# Wanted to change the url of responsive image in typo3 for each devices

Tags: javascript, typo3

I just want to apply my custom url generated by my custom extension installed in typo3 and the url generated by this extension should be apply for the responsive-image in the front-end pages.
Please guide me how I can do it becuase for now it uses it's inbuilt functionality to crop image and store url. I just want to replace those urls with my custom urls.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I just wanted to change the data attribute url for all cropVariants.

Comment: If you just want to change the data attribute url for all cropVariants then please reword your question by editing and delete your comment here afterwards. The task would be completely different in TYPO3 than it would be understood in the question currently. THANKS!